# How to Display Two Scrolling TextViews At Once

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitextview

I'd like to display two windows on screen with scrolling text in them e.g. top window will have one bible translation while the bottom view would have another.

Ideally, I'd like them to stay in sync so they're both showing the same point in their respective translations (i.e. switch to John Ch1 in top view, bottom view follows and does same).  But for now I'm just curious how to get these into two seperate viewable windows.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty, I dont think you have the screen space to do this for the iPhone in such a way that is visually comfortable for the user.

That aside, the best method would depend on how the rest of your app is built. You can create a view that contains two UITextViews in it, each taking up roughly half the screen. You should be able to scroll one as a response to the other scrolling, though I haven't done this, so I cannot tell you how to do it exactly.

Another option that you have is to use a main UITextView, and then a second UIModalView that is overlaid above it. It all depends on the app structure.

Just to note, unless you have specific markers for points of translation, it would be very hard to have them sync up in that way. You could try to match line numbers, or something like that, but due to languages being so different, one might take 3 lines, and a translation might take 4 to say the same thing.

Comment: +1 It is unlikely that the iPhone screen will have room for two text views at once and scrolling one but not the other will be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This is a fairly basic question, so you should perhaps revisit the [iOS Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW14), but in a nutshell, you'd have two UITextView elements inside a view in your application, and you can synchronize between them using the built in setter method

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two needs here:

(1) You need to create a data model that can hold the translations and link each chapter and verse in each translation to the chapter and verse in all the other translations. For that, I would suggest learning Core Data. Be prepared to spend some time learning it.

(2) You need to display the translations. For this I would suggest you use two UITextViews in the same containing view. However, as [Karoly S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812715/karoly-s) noted, there really isn't room on an iphone screen for two text views. I would recommend using two views connect by a [flip transition](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW26) which will allow you to have one translation on a full screen and then flip over to the other translation. The user could flip rapidly back and forth to compare.